# Show details from 3 drop down menus

Tags: javascript, html

I have page on a website I'm doing for college and I've a problem with the registration page. I want a new window to open with the details I have entered. Below is the code I was given that shows the data that's entered into one drop down menu but the birthday one has 3 menus, one for day, month, year. I need help receiving the code from these 3 drop down menus rather than just one. Thanks for your help!

```
function getdropdownvalue()
    {
        var range = document.form1.DOBDay.selectedIndex
        return document.form1.DOBDay.options[range].value
    }



       <body>
        <form action="" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="checkdetails()">
      <table bgcolor="white" width="700" border="0" align="center">
      <col width="200">
      <col width="200">


        <tr>
        <th colspan = "2" align = "center" bgcolor="grey"> Fill the form to sign up. </th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px">Fields marked with * are mandatory</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>Name*</td>
          <td>Surname*</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td><label>
            <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" class="info" />
          <td><label>
            <input type="text" name="txtsurname" id="txtsurname" class="info" />
          </label></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td> Create Username*</td>
        <td> Birthday</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" class="info"/>
        </label></td>




        <td><select name="DOBMonth">
        <option>    Month  </option>
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
        <option value="April">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="August">August</option>
        <option value="September">September</option>
        <option value="October">October</option>
        <option value="November">November</option>
        <option value="December">December</option>
    </select>

    <select name="DOBDay">
        <option> Day </option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>

    <select name="DOBYear">
        <option> Year </option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="1999">1998</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
        <option value="1990">1990</option>
        <option value="1989">1989</option>
        <option value="1988">1988</option>
        <option value="1987">1987</option>
        <option value="1986">1986</option>
        <option value="1985">1985</option>
        <option value="1984">1984</option>
        <option value="1983">1983</option>
        <option value="1982">1982</option>
        <option value="1981">1981</option>
        <option value="1980">1980</option>
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        <option value="1978">1978</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1974">1974</option>
        <option value="1973">1973</option>
        <option value="1972">1972</option>
        <option value="1971">1971</option>
        <option value="1970">1970</option>
        <option value="1969">1969</option>
        <option value="1968">1968</option>
        <option value="1967">1967</option>
        <option value="1966">1966</option>
        <option value="1965">1965</option>
        <option value="1964">1964</option>
        <option value="1963">1963</option>
        <option value="1962">1962</option>
        <option value="1961">1961</option>
        <option value="1960">1960</option>
        <option value="1959">1959</option>
        <option value="1958">1958</option>
        <option value="1957">1957</option>
        <option value="1956">1956</option>
        <option value="1955">1955</option>
        <option value="1954">1954</option>
        <option value="1953">1953</option>
        <option value="1952">1952</option>
        <option value="1951">1951</option>
        <option value="1950">1950</option>
        <option value="1949">1949</option>
        <option value="1948">1948</option>
        <option value="1947">1947</option>
    </select>




        <tr>
          <td>Email*</td>
          <td>Confirm Email*</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td><label>
            <input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail(txtemail)" />
          <td><label>
            <input type="text" name="txtemail2" id="txtemail2" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail2(txtemail2)"/>
          </label></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>Password*</td>
          <td>Confirm Pasword*</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td><label>
            <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="info"/>
          <td><label>
            <input type="password" name="txtpassword2" id="txtpassword2" class="info"/>
          </label></td>
        </tr>


        <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px">**Passwords must be at least 8 characters in lenght.</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>


          <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="terms" value="terms" id="terms" />
              I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
            </td></tr>
            <br><br><br>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label>
              <input type="radio" name="notify" value="notify" id="notify" />
              I want to receive notifications by text/email about new products in stock.</label>
              </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
        <td><label>
          <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login" onclick="checkdetails()" />
        </label></td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, Do you just want to get the dropdown list values using js?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Like if i have entered 04 02 1994 into these three drop down menus id want it to open a window saying something like you have entered 04 02 1994.

Comment: Check the answer posted, I think that what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the value of all the elements you need one by one (since you say you want month and day in numeric format I get the index of these elements not the value)

```
function getdropdownvalue()
{
      var month = document.form1.DOBMonth.selectedIndex;
      var day = document.form1.DOBDay.selectedIndex;
      var year =   document.form1.DOBYear.options[document.form1.DOBDay.selectedIndex].value;
      alert(month+' '+day+' '+year);
      return month+' '+day+' '+year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I give you the solution for that, I noticed in your code that you are missing a few closing tags, filling the dropdowns in your code, use of table for formatting etc. These are few suggestions :

1. Fill the dropdowns using JS.
2. Use a good editor which helps you identify missed tags.
3. Add `id` to your `select`/`input` statements for easier working through JS.
4. You a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) so that its easy to format your page and also avoid usage of `<table>` for formatting of the page.

That's a simple snippet for  you:

```js
function a() {
  var m = document.getElementById("DOBMonth");
  var y = document.getElementById("DOBYear");
  var d = document.getElementById("DOBDay");
  alert(" D:"+d.options[d.selectedIndex].value+"  M:"+m.options[m.selectedIndex].value+" Y:"+y.options[m.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```html
<select name="DOBMonth" id="DOBMonth">
  <option> Month </option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
  <option value="March">March</option>
  <option value="April">April</option>
  <option value="May">May</option>
  <option value="June">June</option>
  <option value="July">July</option>
  <option value="August">August</option>
  <option value="September">September</option>
  <option value="October">October</option>
  <option value="November">November</option>
  <option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="DOBDay" id="DOBDay">
  <option> Day </option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="DOBYear"  id="DOBYear">
  <option> Year </option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2009">2009</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2006">2006</option>
  <option value="2005">2005</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
  <option value="2001">2001</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="1999">1998</option>
  <option value="1998">1998</option>
  <option value="1997">1997</option>
  <option value="1996">1996</option>
  <option value="1995">1995</option>
  <option value="1994">1994</option>
  <option value="1993">1993</option>
  <option value="1992">1992</option>
  <option value="1991">1991</option>
  <option value="1990">1990</option>
  <option value="1989">1989</option>
  <option value="1988">1988</option>
  <option value="1987">1987</option>
  <option value="1986">1986</option>
  <option value="1985">1985</option>
  <option value="1984">1984</option>
  <option value="1983">1983</option>
  <option value="1982">1982</option>
  <option value="1981">1981</option>
  <option value="1980">1980</option>
  <option value="1979">1979</option>
  <option value="1978">1978</option>
  <option value="1977">1977</option>
  <option value="1976">1976</option>
  <option value="1975">1975</option>
  <option value="1974">1974</option>
  <option value="1973">1973</option>
  <option value="1972">1972</option>
  <option value="1971">1971</option>
  <option value="1970">1970</option>
  <option value="1969">1969</option>
  <option value="1968">1968</option>
  <option value="1967">1967</option>
  <option value="1966">1966</option>
  <option value="1965">1965</option>
  <option value="1964">1964</option>
  <option value="1963">1963</option>
  <option value="1962">1962</option>
  <option value="1961">1961</option>
  <option value="1960">1960</option>
  <option value="1959">1959</option>
  <option value="1958">1958</option>
  <option value="1957">1957</option>
  <option value="1956">1956</option>
  <option value="1955">1955</option>
  <option value="1954">1954</option>
  <option value="1953">1953</option>
  <option value="1952">1952</option>
  <option value="1951">1951</option>
  <option value="1950">1950</option>
  <option value="1949">1949</option>
  <option value="1948">1948</option>
  <option value="1947">1947</option>
</select>

<button onclick="a()">Click</button>
```

Comment: add ids to the `<select>` with the `id` names you use in the JS.

Comment: the alert wasnt appearing when i submitted it. but it works with the answer below this one. thanks for your help though!